# R - Change a value based on Date evaluation

Tags: r

apologies if this has been answered, but I've looked for the last hour and cannot find a simple answer to my question.

Very simply - I want to change / replace a value in a data frame observation based on a date conditional.

Example - (this is wrong but for illustration)

```
HR <-replace(HR$Status, HR$Call.Date < as.Date("01/01/2019"), "closed")
```

Where I want to replace the HR$Status value with "closed" if the HR$Call.Date is "before" (less than) 01/01/2019.  Any help is appreciated or if there is a current open question for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What's wrong with your example code? Is `HR$Status` a character or a factor column? If the latter, is "closed" a valid level in that factor?

Comment: Got it - I will do that moving forward.  I couldnt "get it to work" is why i didnt include it

Comment: Typically this sort of question (assignment of character value "won't work") will be foundering on a lack of recognition that the target column is a factor that does not include a level corresponding to the desired assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `Status` is of `character` class and `Call.Date` is `Date` class - you can do what you need to with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
HR %>%
  mutate(Status = if_else(Call.Date < as.Date("01/01/2019"), "closed", Status))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will try that

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!

Comment: dont laugh.. how do i do that?

Comment: No problem - it’s the check mark / tick next to the up / down arrows to the left of my answer - thanks.